# Splitting text without losing separator

Tags: python

I want to split a string without losing the separators. I have 2 different separators: "<" and ">".

So with a string like `"<\abc>d<\e><\f>ghi<\j>"` , the result should be

```
["<\abc>","d","<\e>","<\f>","ghi","<\j>"]
```

Comment: So, your separators are actually `<\\.*?>`, in regex.

Comment: Which is information you can combine with the answer to the linked question to solve your problem.

Comment: Your question has been answered in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876007/how-to-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators-in-it/55878409#55878409) :)

Comment: Thank you @nero ! I looked around quite a bit, but couldn't find it.