# How to split a string and keep the separators in it

Tags: python, regex

@edzech asked how was it possible to split a string and keep the separators in it. His question was [marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875494/splitting-text-without-losing-separator), whereas the approach here is different than the "duplicate".

We want to split a string but by keeping the delimiters in it, we don't want them to be separated.
In brief, for `<abc>d<e><f>ghi<j>`, we want:

```py
['<abc>', 'd', '<e>', '<f>', 'ghi', '<j>']
```

instead of:

```py
['<', 'abc', '>' 'd', '<', 'e', '>', '<', 'f', '>', 'ghi', '<', 'j', '>']
```

Using `split` does not help since it will *split* according to the separator. We want to keep it attached to its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proposed, solution a single opening `<` or closing `>` which are not part of a pair <> are excluded from the result.

If you also want to keep a `<` or `>` you could use:

```
<[^<>]*>|(?:(?!<[^<>]*>).)+
```

Explanation

- `<[^<>]*>` Match opening `<`, then 0+ times not `>`, then a closing `>`
- `|` Or
- `(?:(?!<[^<>]*>).)+` Tempered greedy token, match any char if what is directly on the right is not the opening till closing pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nc4Jwt/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fxIic3)

For example:

```
import re
content = "<abc>d<e><f>ghi<j>test><g>"
result = re.findall(r"<[^<>]*>|(?:(?!<[^<>]*>).)+", content)
print(result)
```

Result

```
['<abc>', 'd', '<e>', '<f>', 'ghi', '<j>', 'test>', '<g>']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```py
import re

content = "<abc>d<e><f>ghi<j>"
result = re.findall(r"<.*?>|[^<>]+", content)

print(result)
```

Output:

```py
['<abc>', 'd', '<e>', '<f>', 'ghi', '<j>']
```

Explanations:

- regex `<.*?>` means everything that matches `<content>`
- regex `[^<>]+` means everything else

In brief, `findall` will find everything that matches `<content>`, otherwise, everything else. That way, the content will be split without losing the separators.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use split with this regex

```
(?<=>)(?=[a-z<])|(?<=[a-z>])(?=<)
```

https://regex101.com/r/WNy5n9/1

It's nothing more than 2 option's with paired lookbehind/ahead assertions.

Expanded

```
   (?<= > )                      # Behind a  >
   (?= [a-z<] )                  # Ahead either a-z or <
|                              # or,
   (?<= [a-z>] )                 # Behind either a-z or >
   (?= < )                       # Ahead a  <
```

***Update***
Note that in versions of Python prior to version 3.7 splitting
on an empty match was not handled correctly.
Presumably they couldn't tell the difference between an empty
string and / or how to do the *bump along* on zero-width matches.

Seems like they pulled their heads out of their a** now in version 3.7,
so here you go..

**Demo**

Version 3.7.3

```
>>> import sys
>>> print( sys.version )
3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Code

```
>>> import re
>>> rx = re.compile( r"(?<=>)(?=[a-z<])|(?<=[a-z>])(?=<)" )
>>> s = "<abc>d<e><f>ghi<j>test><g>"
>>> x =  re.split( rx, s )
>>> print ( x )
['<abc>', 'd', '<e>', '<f>', 'ghi', '<j>', 'test>', '<g>']
```